# how to find affine formula

Tags: linear-algebra, affine-geometry

I'm struggling with finding formula of affine transformation where we have:

$(1,3) \to (3,5)$

$(2,1) \to (0,6)$

$(4,0) \to (0,11)$

I know in affine transformation we have $f(p)=q_o+\psi(\vec{p_0p})$ but have no idea how to solve this, would be greatful for hints or links to similiar problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with your notation for an affine transformation, but here's my take.

Associated with the affine transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ is a $2\times2$ matrix and a vector, i.e.,

$$T(x,y) = \begin{bmatrix}
    a       & b \\
    c       & d \\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
    x \\
    y \\
\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}
    e \\
    f \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

If you multiply it out, you have $T(x,y)=(ax+by+e,cx+dy+f)$. You are given 6 inputs and 6 outputs, so you should be able to solve for the 6 unknowns $a,b,..,f$ from there by substituting the various $(x,y)$ pairs.

You can check your answer with [Wolfram Alpha's solution](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%20%2B%20a*1%20%2B%20b*3%20%3D%203%2C%20f%20%2B%20c*1%20%2B%20d*3%20%3D%205%2C%20e%20%2B%20a*2%20%2B%20b*1%20%3D%200%2C%20f%20%2B%20c*2%20%2B%20d*1%20%3D%206%2C%20e%20%2B%20a*4%20%3D%200%2C%20f%20%2B%20c*4%20%3D%2011).